# Magento 2 - RateRequest Get Checkout Phone Number

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

The Shipping Courier API requires the Customer Phone Number to get the shipping rates. I'm using RateRequest to get all the information, including the Destination information, but i can't figure out how to get the Phone number. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way, may be help you:

```
$quote = null;
$items = $request->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
    /** @var Quote $quote */
    $quote = $item->getQuote();
    break;
}
```

Now you have the quote. You can access the quote billing/shipping address. Ex:

```
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->getTelephone(); // phone number
```